# backbone.js: how to explicitly request json from a flask endpoint?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

So I have the a file, `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<head>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="content">
    <h1>User Manager</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="page"></div>
</div>



<!-- Third-Party Libraries -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>

<!-- Application core -->
<script src="./src/common.js"></script>
<script src="./src/application.js"></script>

<!-- Modules -->
</body>
</html>
```

that references two javascript files, `common.js` and `application.js.`

`common.js` just holds all-purpose functions, and for now looks like:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

`application.js` holds a Backbone.js application and looks as follows, following the example at http://backbonetutorials.com/:

```
/** PREFILTER - points to our instance **/

$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
});

/** COLLECTIONS **/

var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/users'
});

/** ROUTES **/

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'home'
    }
})


/** VIEWS **/

var userList = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.page',
    render: function() {
        var users = new Users();
        users.fetch({
            success: function () {
                this.$el.html("CONTENT HERE");  
            }
        })

    }

});


/** INSTANCES **/

/* VIEWS */
var userList = new userList();

/* ROUTES */
var router = new Router()

router.on('route:home', function() {
    userList.render();
})

/** START HISTORY **/
Backbone.history.start();
```

I can use the Chrome developer tools to tell that this works with the example page provided by the site -- it pulls the json object and previews it.

However, when I switch the prefilter string over to my own heroku instance, I get the following in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {{our instance}}/users. Origin null is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This happens even though I can go to `{{our instance}}/users` in a browser and query it via Postman. My guess is that this has to do with the way that I'm having Backbone retrieve the data, that it is pulling it via a standard request rather than explicitly asking for JSON. Is there a best practice here so that I can grab the objects at this endpoint?

Comment: Is everything being served from the same place or is your `$.ajaxPrefilter` there to send the AJAX requests to a different place than where everything else came from? A quick bit of googling for "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" will lead you to many SO questions that are probably about the same problem you're facing.

Comment: Everything is being served by the same heroku instance, and the prefilter is just there for simplicity. Googling in the manner that you suggest led me to conclude that the issue was with the manner in which I was requesting the data via Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that `XMLHttpRequest cannot load {{our instance}}/users. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` is related to **cdnjs** not using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Try to serve those files yourself (instead of cdnjs) and see if that solves your problem